# Increase FPS in Pygame: Mac vs Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, pygame, frame-rate

I generated a program on my Windows laptop using pygame and python where white stripes run vertically across a black screen. When I increase the FPS variable on my Windows laptop and run it, the white stripes will run faster. When I use this same code on a Mac, the FPS wont increase past about 55 FPS. For example, I could run the code on Windows at 500 FPS and the stripes would move faster. Then I could run the code on Mac at 500 FPS but the stripes would still move at about 55 FPS. I could make the FPS slower than 55 FPS on a Mac but not faster. Why is this? How can I increase the FPS on Mac so that the white stripes will run faster?

```
import pygame, sys
import time
pygame.init()
FPS=500
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

size =(480,320)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
WHITE =(255,255,255)
BLACK =(0,0,0)
player_rect0 =pygame.Rect(-120,0,60,320)
player_rect1 =pygame.Rect(0,0,60,320)
player_rect2 =pygame.Rect(120,0,60,320)
player_rect3 =pygame.Rect(240,0,60,320)
player_rect4 =pygame.Rect(360,0,60,320)


direction = "right"
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, player_rect0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, player_rect1)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, player_rect2)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, player_rect3)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, player_rect4)

    if direction == "right":
        player_rect0.centerx += 1
    if player_rect0.right >(-60+120):
        player_rect0 = pygame.Rect(-120,0,60,320)
###
    if direction == "right":
        player_rect1.centerx += 1
    if player_rect1.right >(60+120):
        player_rect1 = pygame.Rect(0,0,60,320)
###
    if direction == "right":
        player_rect2.centerx += 1
    if player_rect2.right >(180+120):
        player_rect2 = pygame.Rect(120,0,60,320)
###
    if direction == "right":
        player_rect3.centerx += 1
    if player_rect3.right >(300+120):
        player_rect3 = pygame.Rect(240,0,60,320)
###
    if direction == "right":
        player_rect4.centerx += 1
    if player_rect4.right >(420+120):
        player_rect4 = pygame.Rect(360,0,60,320)


    clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(clock.get_fps()))
```

Answer (score 0):

FPS is usually according to your CPU speed. The slower the computer, the slower the FPS. It is based on how fast your computer can process it.

Comment: The Mac cpu has a 2.66 GHz processor and the Windows cpu has a 2.5 Ghz processor. So I do not think it was to do with the speed of the computers. Any other reasons why I cannot increase the FPS past 55 on the Mac? Thanks!

Comment: I've done some google searching and alot of people have problems with Mac's just clocking the FPS at 55. Sorry, cannot help otherwise :c